# Why does installation of some Python packages require Visual Studio?

Tags: python, visual-studio

Say, you are installing a Python package for pyEnchant or crfsuite, etc. It fails to install and in the error trace it says some `.bat` (or `.dll`) file is missing.

A few forums suggest you install Visual Studio and a few others give work-arounds like cygwin, mingw, etc.

Why do some Python packages require Visual Studio?

Comment: That's generally the easiest way to make sure you have all of the appropriate development DLLs - as you point out, there are other work-arounds.

Comment: How are the dlls required for python packages related to MS Visual studio  ? Can you please elaborate

Comment: I don't see what's confusing you. Some Python packages require certain DLLs to be installed for their functionality to work. Visual Studio installs, among other things, those DLLs. Therefore, if you want to use those packages, *one way* to install the DLLs is to install VS.

Comment: Understood, Thank you ☺

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Why do some Python packages require Visual Studio?

Installation from source of CPython extension modules written in C requires a C compiler. Visual Studio provides one such compiler.

To avoid it, use binary installers such as [these](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/).

Also, due to licensing restrictions, an extension module may not install some dlls automatically and you have to install Visual Studio that provides these dlls manually.

Comment: Great. Thanks a tonn.